# Zend framework error in magento 2

Tags: php, zend-framework, magento2

I am developing ecommerce website in magento 2. I got error when I am adding products from home page:

> Zend\Uri\Exception\InvalidUriException: URI is not valid and cannot be
>   converted into a string in
>   /var/www/html/voylite/vendor/zendframework/zend-uri/src/Uri.php:359
>   Stack trace: #0
>   /var/www/html/voylite/vendor/zendframework/zend-http/src/Header/AbstractLocation.php(98):
>   Zend\Uri\Uri->toString() #1
>   /var/www/html/voylite/vendor/zendframework/zend-http/src/Header/AbstractLocation.php(133):
>   Zend\Http\Header\AbstractLocation->getUri() #2
>   /var/www/html/voylite/vendor/zendframework/zend-http/src/PhpEnvironment/Response.php(98):
>   Zend\Http\Header\AbstractLocation->toString() #3
>   /var/www/html/voylite/var/generation/Magento/Framework/App/Response/Http/Interceptor.php(310):
>   Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Response->sendHeaders() #4
>   /var/www/html/voylite/vendor/zendframework/zend-http/src/PhpEnvironment/Response.php(128):
>   Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor->sendHeaders() #5
>   /var/www/html/voylite/var/generation/Magento/Framework/App/Response/Http/Interceptor.php(336):
>   Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Response->send() #6
>   /var/www/html/voylite/vendor/magento/framework/HTTP/PhpEnvironment/Response.php(44):
>   Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor->send() #7
>   /var/www/html/voylite/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(146):
>   Magento\Framework\HTTP\PhpEnvironment\Response->sendResponse() #8
>   /var/www/html/voylite/var/generation/Magento/Framework/App/Response/Http/Interceptor.php(117):
>   Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor->___callPlugins('sendResponse',
>   Array, Array) #9
>   /var/www/html/voylite/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(185):
>   Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor->sendResponse() #10
>   /var/www/html/voylite/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(156):
>   Magento\Framework\App\Http->handleDeveloperMode(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap),
>   Object(Zend\Uri\Exception\InvalidUriException)) #11
>   /var/www/html/voylite/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(263):
>   Magento\Framework\App\Http->catchException(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap),
>   Object(Zend\Uri\Exception\InvalidUriException)) #12
>   /var/www/html/voylite/index.php(38):
>   Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
>   #13 {main}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URI which you have set is invalid, fix it. Difficult to offer more help without actually seeing what your input is.

Comment: Then something has changed.

Comment: I am not able to recognise what's the issue

Comment: add to cart form action link: http://205.147.100.198/voylite/checkout/cart/add/uenc/aHR0cDovLzIwNS4xNDcuMTAwLjE5OC92b3lsaXRlLw,,/product/343/

Answer (score 1):

For further help, I've got the exact same error while developping an Ajax Controller/Action.

I was preparing the **$result** object to send the response :

```
$result = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);
```

And in some cases, set the redirection URL, depending of the treatement result :

```
$result->setUrl($this->_url->getUrl('checkout/onepage/success'));
```

But in one specific case, I've forgotten to set the URL and it caused the previous error. I've struggle a bit before finding out that the problem came from this little mistake.

I hope this may help someone else.

Answer (score 0):

It happens if URL to which redirection is being sent is invalid or blank.
There is problem with this error stack because we can not find the actual line of code from where it is happened because error is starting after  `toURL` method. Which is the part of ZF2 core.